# Uniform continuity over subsets of closed intervals

Tags: continuity, solution-verification

Could someone please verify my solution to the second part of Carothers, Ch. 8 Exercise 50?

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous over $(0, 2)$ and on $(1,3)$ is $f$ uniformly continuous on $(0,3)$? If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[n, n+1]$ for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is $f$ necessarily uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

I believe the first part is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752190/uniform-continuity-on-union-of-intervals), but the closest answer I could find for the second part was [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770157/uniform-continuity-on-subsets-of-closed-intervals), which is actually its converse.

**Answer**: If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[n, n+1]$ for every on $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, the function is *not* necessarily uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, the function taking the values $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ but over the interval $[n, n+1]$, it is (which I try to show below).

Because $f'$ increases monotonically, $|f'(x)| = 2|x|$ attains a maximum at $n$ or $n+1$ and so it is bound by $2\max(|n|, |n+1|)$. The maximum change that can occur in a given function over the chosen interval is $|f(x) - f(x+\delta)| \leq|\delta|(2\max(|n|, |n+1|)$ and so $\frac{|f(x)-f(x+\delta)|}{2\max(|n|, |n+1|)} \leq \delta$ and so it should be sufficient to choose
$$|\delta| < \min\Big(\frac{\epsilon}{2\max(|n|, |n+1|}, x-n, n+1-x \Big)$$
where $|\delta| < |x-n|$ and $|n+1-x|$ to ensure that $|x|$ and $|x-\delta|$ remain in the interval $[n, n+1]$. Because $\delta$ does not depend on $x$ (besides restricting it to $[n, n+1]$), the function $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[n, n+1]$.

Is this solution ok? I tried to plug $\delta$ into $|x^2 - (x-\delta)^2|$ but started getting confused with all the inequalities.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, part consider $f(x)=\exp(x)$.

Comment: So, because $f(x) = f'(x) = \exp(x)$, we know that $\exp(n) < \exp(x) < exp(n+1)$. As earlier, using $|f(x)-f(x-\delta)| < |\delta|\max|f'(x)|$, we can choose $|\delta| < \epsilon/\exp(n+1)$ so that $|f(x) - f(x-\delta)| < \epsilon$, again showing that uniform cont. over intervals does not imply uniform cont. over their union (as $\exp(x)$ is not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.)

I'm still thinking it'd be messy to plug $\delta$ in, but is this correct?

Comment: Actually, every continuous function over an interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem). So if you know that $\exp$ is not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$, then you get directly a counterexample.

Comment: Ah, so any continuous functions that are not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb{R}$ could have worked, as the closed intervals are compact (thus uniformly continuous). That makes things much simpler. Are we assuming anything away w/ this argument? I don't think we are.

Comment: @akm You are right, indeed, you can choose your favourite non-uniformly continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, it will give a correct counterexample.